# List git branches in directory using bash with formatting

Tags: git, bash, shell, ubuntu, formatting

I wants to list git branches in a set of directories using bash.

Now I just want to format the branch name differently if it's "master". In other words, if the branch is 'master' I want to display it in Blue or any other color.

Comment: What difficulty are you having in achieving this?

Comment: Would `...|grep --color 'master$'` do?

Comment: @Biffen That'll fail to display any non-matching lines though.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes. Not sure what OP wants. `...|grep --color '\(master\)\?$'`, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to `cd` around for this. Just use something like this

```
reset=$(tput sgr0)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
for dir in directory_name_1 directory_name_2 ...; do
    branch=$(GIT_DIR="$dir/.git" git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

    color=
    if [ master = "$branch" ]; then
        color=$blue
    fi

    printf '%s: %s%s%s\n' "${dir##/*}" "$color" "$branch" "$reset"
done
```

Use `tput` to get the correct control codes for the current terminal for reset attributes (`sgr0`) and for set foreground color (`setaf`) to blue (default color 4).

Comment: that is beautiful, the tput though give me this error: tput: unknown terminfo capability 'srg0'